# How to run JavaScript function from GWT Java with JSNI?

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

Can't understand from the manual: how actually to run JS function from Java?

For example, I have a function in my html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function foo() {
        alert('Foo!');
    }
</script>
```

The following module shows two buttons, only second of which works:

```
public class Test_GoogleWeb_JSNI_01 implements EntryPoint {

public void onModuleLoad() {

    Button fooButton = new Button("Foo!");
    fooButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            fooRunner();
        };
    });


    HTML fooButtonNative = new HTML();
    fooButtonNative.setHTML("<input type='button' value='Foo Native' onclick='foo()'>");

    RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
    rootPanel.add(fooButton);
    rootPanel.add(fooButtonNative);

}

public static native void fooRunner() /*-{
  foo();
}-*/;
}
```

It is said in manual, that native functions implemented within nested frame, which explains the situation. But how to run JS functions then?

**UPDATE 1**
The following works.

Java:

```
public static native void fooRunner() /*-{
  $doc.fooRunner();
}-*/;
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    document.fooRunner = function foo() {
        alert('Foo!');
    }
</script>
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You answered your question yourself. There is no better way for a very simple reason: there are multiple ways to deploy GWT app, running in iframe is only one of the options. So that's why you have to use $wnd variable to access external JS function, so in case if you switch the linker , your still code will work just fine.

Comment: can you call a javascrypt method that returns an object? and use that object?