# Invoke external function from jsni in GWT

Tags: gwt, jsni

I have a function defined in a .js file, which is included in the main .html file with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" 
    src="js/script.js"></script>
```

I also have a JSNI method that invokes a function that is defined in the js file:

```
public native void addJsModule(String name) /*-{
        addNewSection(name);
    }-*/;
```

When I invoke the java method, I get this exception:

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Exception caught: (ReferenceError) @client.registros.home.RegistyHome::addJsModule(Ljava/lang/String;)([string: 'acercade']): addNewSection is not defined
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GWT code runs (by default) in a hidden iframe, where your script is not available. There's a `$wnd` variable referencing the Window object of the enclosing browsing context (where your script has been loaded). You therefore have to prefix your function with `$wnd` to reference the function as defined in the outer browsing context:

```
public native void addJsModule(String name) /*-{
    $wnd.addNewSection(name);
}-*/;
```

See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#writing

> Note that the code did not reference the JavaScript `window` object directly inside the method. When accessing the browser’s window and document objects from JSNI, you must reference them as `$wnd` and `$doc`, respectively. Your compiled script runs in a nested frame, and `$wnd` and `$doc` are automatically initialized to correctly refer to the host page’s window and document.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your javascript-method available by storing it in a shared object.

A commonly used construct is to store the method in `$doc`. In JavaScript save your method like this:

```
document.addNewSection = new function(name) {addNewSection(name);};
```

Afterwards use it in the jsni-body of your GWT native method like this:

```
$doc.addNewSection(name);
```

(you can also use JSNI `$wnd` with JS `window`, if you want)

See also:

- [How to run JavaScript function from GWT Java with JSNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617055/how-to-run-javascript-function-from-gwt-java-with-jsni) (except that it does not cover parameters)
- And the official documentation at: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#writing

Comment: Thanks. I added this code:
    document.addNewSection = new function(name) {
 addNewSection(name);
};

And I'm still getting this exception:  $doc.addNewSection is not a function

Comment: try `document.addNewSection = new function (name) { alert ('call received in Javascript'); };` and tell us, whether you see a popup.